# Discord bot doesnt respond to the command with user input

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to make the command so it shows information about the invite that the user gives to the bot.
But when I try r!invitecheck the bot doesn't respond, or give a error.
I've tried asking on a coding discord server someone helped but it still didn't work.

Here is the code

```
const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift();

switch (args[0]) {
    case 'invitecheck':
        if (!args.length) {
            return msg.channel.send(`You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`);
        }
        client.fetchInvite(args[1])
            .then(invite => {
                const test12 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setAuthor(invite.guild.name)
                    .addField(`Inviter`, ` ${invite.inviter.username} (<@${invite.inviter.id})>`)
                    .addField(`Total members`, invite.memberCount)
                    .addField(`Owner`, ` ${invite.guild.owner} (<@${invite.guild.ownerID}>)`)
                    .addField(`Region`, ` ${invite.guild.region}`)
                    .addField(`Verification level`, ` ${invite.guild.verificationLevel}`)
                console.log(invite)
                msg.channel.send(test12)
            })
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because how you declare your command, `Array.shift()` removes the first element of the array, it should work if you check for the command instead:

```js
const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift();

switch (command) {
    case 'invitecheck':
        if (!args.length) 
            return msg.channel.send(`You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`);
        client.fetchInvite(args[0])
            .then(invite => {
                const test12 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setAuthor(invite.guild.name)
                    .addField(`Inviter`, ` ${invite.inviter.username} (<@${invite.inviter.id})>`)
                    .addField(`Total members`, invite.memberCount)
                    .addField(`Owner`, ` ${invite.guild.owner} (<@${invite.guild.ownerID}>)`)
                    .addField(`Region`, ` ${invite.guild.region}`)
                    .addField(`Verification level`, ` ${invite.guild.verificationLevel}`)
                console.log(invite)
                msg.channel.send(test12)
            })
        break;
}
```